# correct return type for C function?

Tags: c, function, pointers, return-type

I am using an array of strings inside my function declared like this

```
char (*array)[PATH_MAX] = malloc (1000 * sizeof *array);
```

Allocating 1000 char pointers of size `PATH_MAX` (1024).

I want the function to return that specific data structure, i.e. return the pointer `array`. But I can't manage to choose the correct return type.

```
warning: returning 'char (*)[1024]' from a function with return type 'int' makes integer from pointer without a cast [-Wint-conversion]
```

I get that I can't have `int` as return type, but `char**` doesn't work either.

```
warning: returning 'char (*)[1024]' from a function with incompatible return type 'char **' [-Wincompatible-pointer-types]
```

I've tried using `char (*)[1024]` as return type, but it gives me generic C error messages, leading me to believe that I am not using the correct syntax.

```
error: expected identifier or '(' before ')' token
   38 | char (*)[1024] read_dir (char *path) {
      |        ^
```

Is there a correct syntax for achieving this or am I just doing it wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Time for `typedef`

```
typedef char arr1k_char[1000];

arr1k_char *foo(int n) {
    arr1k_char *x = malloc(n * sizeof *x);
    return x;
}
```

https://ideone.com/Cqxa61

Comment: BTW: do not hide `*` in typedef... it may seem nice, but avoid the temptation to do `typedef char (*ptr_array1k_char)[1000];`

Comment: Your solution also solved my problem. Thank you. I also found out that using what at first seemed to be extra fluff - in the form of a typedef - actually saved me from repeating myself in writing long type declarations every time I would create a variable of the particular type.
So I'll accept your answer as the most helpful. Thanks again!

Comment: Thanks for the feedback :)

Answer (score 4):

You need to define the function as follows:

```
char (*read_dir(char *path))[PATH_MAX] {
```

This specifies the return type as a pointer to an array of size `PATH_MAX` of `char *`.

Comment: Your suggestion did the trick. Rudimentary and no extra frills to get it working. Thank you!